Changes to splash and icon in app.json not reflecting in Expo app
I've recently updated the splash and icon sections in my app.json for my Expo project. However, when I run the app, the changes don't seem to be reflected. I've tried restarting the Expo server and clearing the cache, but the old splash screen and icon are still showing up.
Here are the specific steps I took:
Updated the splash and icon paths in app.json.
Ran

npx expo prebuild --clean
npx expo prebuild

part of app.json;
"icon": "./assets/images/icon.png",
"scheme": "myapp",
"userInterfaceStyle": "automatic",
"splash": {
  "image": "./assets/images/splash.png",
  "resizeMode": "contain",
  "backgroundColor": "#0D0118"
},


Deleting ios/build file, and then npm run ios command fixed.
